# Assignin labelvalues in curl command

Tags: python, curl, prometheus

```
os.system('curl --insecure -g  https://ab/api/v1/query?query=m{site_name="a"}')
```

//Whenever i am running it I am getting an error
    {"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"parse error at char 25: unexpected \"}\" in label matching, expected string"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to query by label value in your curl command as assigning new labels isn't possible via the HTTP API.

The following example will return all series that match the selector given in your question:

```
os.system('curl --insecure -g \'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?match[]=mulpi_Version{site_name="BishopGate"}\'')
```

This is covered in the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/api/#querying-label-values)

Note it would probably be better to use a library to query the API rather than making a curl request using Python.

Comment: The same curl command is running in shell but inn script I amfacing the issue {"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"parse error at char 25: unexpected identifier \"BishopGate\" in label matches.

Comment: Any idea how we can parse the "BishopGate".I tried by \"BishopGate\"

Comment: @ush Glad I could help. Have you considered using a library rather than making a curl request in python? Would likely be a lot easier to query the api that way!